# Android - Activity Destroyed when Rotating Tablet

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, screen-size

I have the following problem in my application::

- When the user shuts off the screen on the tablet, turn on again, rotate to  vertical and unclock the lockscreen, the `Activity` was destroyed and the app return to the login screen of the application.
- This problem only occurs in `Activity` that has a list whose`Adapter` has an XML that contains a property valued using `@dimen.xml`.

Exemple:

```
View row = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_attachment_list_item,
                parent, false);
```

**My XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/sp_gen_xl_15dp"
    android:text="@dimen/sp_box_margin_left"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

- That is: if I use `android:padding="@dimen/sp_gen_xl_15dp"` to set padding, `Activity` is destroyed. If I pass any value, "10dp" for example, the `Activity` is not destroyed.

Note: The reported `Activity` already has in the **Manifest** an android tag: configChanges="orientation|screenSize" that serves to not destroy an Activity` when the *tablet* rotates.

**Exemple:**

```
<activity
     Activity"
            android:keepScreenOn="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"></activity>
```

Why does the tag `orientation | screenSize` placed in the `Manifest` only work in Activities that **do not** use **@dimen** in its **XML**?

**I HAVE THE FOLLOWING ERROR WHEN ACTIVITY CRASHED:**

`Binary XML file line #3: Binary XML file line #3: You must supply a layout_height attribute. Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Binary XML file line #3: You must supply a layout_height attribute`

Comment: The big question, in fact, is why aren't you just playing nice and letting the activity be destroyed and re-created like normal? Note that your config changes list is very brittle: it won't catch a lot of other things (like, say, the device being plugged into a docking port). As for returning to the login screen, it sounds like you aren't handling state saving correctly.

Comment: What does your onConfigurationChanged() method look like in your Activity?

Comment: My Activity don't have the method onConfigurationChanged, 
I already tried to overwrite it but it did not work.

Comment: Ted Hopp, the Activity is destroyed but is not recreated again. I dont know why. Other Acitivyts that dont use @dimen are destroyed and created.

Comment: What is the folder structure in your `res` directory. I think the values are not found when you are using the `@dimen/` in configuration changes.

Comment: If the activity seems to not be re-created, that's very odd. Perhaps it's being re-created but immediately finishing (perhaps due to some lost state data). The visual effect would be like it didn't get re-created at all. Is there anything possibly informative in logcat?

Comment: I have the following error when Aciivity is crashed: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Binary XML file line #3: You must supply a layout_height attribute. Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Binary XML file line #3: You must supply a layout_height attribute

Comment: Can you please post the full xml layout??

Comment: My XML just have the textView related. All my XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:padding="@dimen/sp_gen_xl_15dp"
    android:text="@dimen/sp_box_margin_left"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />

Comment: I have another error in other activity in this line:

mCustomerFrameWidthScaled = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.sp_gen_xl_305dp);

Look, the dimen is called again.

Error:  android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException